# Confusion on random variable linearity of expectations

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

I'm confused on why $E(X) = E(X_1) + E(X_2)+· · ·+E(X_n) = np$. How can we multiply the number of elements by $p$ if we do not know if each element in the sum has the same probability? Or just overall why does this work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\operatorname{E}(X_1) = \cdots = \operatorname{E}(X_n) = p$, so $$\operatorname{E}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \operatorname{E}(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname{E}(X_n) = p + \cdots + p = np$$

It was given that $p$ is the probability of success on each trial.  The number of successes on each trial is either $0$ or $1$.  So
$$
\operatorname{E}(X_k) = 0\cdot\Pr(X_k=0) + 1\cdot\Pr(X_k=1) = 0\cdot(1-p) + 1\cdot p.
$$

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify is $p = 1$? As in $p$ is the probability and the total probability or $E(X)$ adds up to 1?

Comment: @stumped : $p$ can be any number between $0$ and $1$. $\qquad$

Comment: How do we know that $E(X_1)= E(X_2) ... =E(X_n)$? Why don't each $E(X_n)$ have a different $p$?

Comment: @stumped : That was given: It said $p$ is the probability of success on EACH trial. $\qquad$

Comment: For the formula for Expected Value: $E(X) = \sum_{s∈S}
p(s)X(s)$. In the answer, $E(X_1) = ... = E(X_n) = np$ so $E(X_1) = p$. I understand that you don't need to use summation because there's only one value, and the $p(s)$ in the formula is $p$ but I'm confused as to why we are allowed to drop the $X(s)$?

Comment: @stumped : The exercise said "Show how Theorem 3 can be used".  That means what it says.  Presumably the _proof_ of Theorem 3 should rely on the "formula for expected value". $\qquad$